# Unity Heyzap 9.10.1 Vungle 4.0.1 not initialized. Runtime error in Android

Tags: heyzap

I have been trying to integrate Heyzap with Vungle, Admob, Chartboost, Unity Ads and Facebook Audience Network.

Except Admob and Vungle, everything else is working fine.
For Admob I am not getting any error. But no Reward Videos are playing. Banner and Interstitial alone working fine.

In case of Vungle, I think Heyzap is trying to play, but due to initialization error, its unable to do so. Attached error below

I am not taking direct apk output from Unity. Its been first exported to Android Studio Project and then I compile all modules to take the apk.

**Platform**

```
Unity - 5.4.3p4
Google play service version - 10.0.1
Heyzap - latest version ( 9.10.1 )
```

**Exception/Error**

```
 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.vungle.publisher.sn>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks;
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sk.<init>() (vungle:46)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sl.get() (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.rl.get() (vungle:10)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sh.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.rw.a(com.vungle.publisher.sf) (vungle:4430)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sf.<init>() (vungle:26)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sg.get() (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.rm.get() (vungle:10)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yr.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yq.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yi.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yh.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yo.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yn.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.ye.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yd.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.qa.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:17)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.pz.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.e.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:24)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.d.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:133)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:18)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.rw.a(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:4415)
     at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:99)
     at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:33)
     at void com.heyzap.sdk.mediation.adapter.VungleAdapter.onStart() (VungleAdapter.java:94)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.xxxx.games.xxxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-vunglePub_724db8a828a3a586b4f4db2f65c96cc0429082ae-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxxx.games.xxxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-vunglePlugin_f8395a7b82d1eaa5336e1b9d607cb5125fc9ed7c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxxx.games.xxxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-4.0.3_2cccecc2fb915338ed2645c765b198c2f7af0284-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxxx.games.xxxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unitydialogplugin_fcfa6cff156e634342ad230b316d5e851da59364-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxxx.games.xxxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unityAds-unspecified-jars_83e46d29cb71456edd501e16a1e657053bcdc7fc-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.xxxx.games.xxxx/files/instant-run/dex/slice-unity-classes_a2
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sk.<init>() (vungle:46)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sl.get() (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.rl.get() (vungle:10)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sh.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.rw.a(com.vungle.publisher.sf) (vungle:4430)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sf.<init>() (vungle:26)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sg.get() (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.rm.get() (vungle:10)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yr.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yq.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yi.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yh.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yo.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yn.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.ye.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yd.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.qa.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:17)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.pz.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.e.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:24)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.d.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:133)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:18)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.rw.a(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:4415)
     at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:99)
     at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:33)
     at void com.heyzap.sdk.mediation.adapter.VungleAdapter.onStart() (VungleAdapter.java:94)
 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.vungle.publisher.sn>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks;
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sk.<init>() (vungle:46)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sl.get() (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.rl.get() (vungle:10)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sh.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.rw.a(com.vungle.publisher.sf) (vungle:4430)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.sf.<init>() (vungle:26)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.sg.get() (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.rm.get() (vungle:10)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yr.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yq.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yi.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:7)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yh.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.yo.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:8)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yn.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.ye.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:12)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.yd.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.qa.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:17)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.pz.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.e.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:24)
     at java.lang.Object com.vungle.publisher.d.get() (vungle:8)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:133)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase_MembersInjector.injectMembers(java.lang.Object) (vungle:18)
     at void com.vungle.publisher.rw.a(com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase) (vungle:4415)
     at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:99)
     at boolean com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.init(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (vungle:33)
     at void com.heyzap.sdk.mediation.adapter.VungleAdapter.onStart() (VungleAdapter.java:94)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are not causing the issues you are experiencing, they are always shown by vungle because of it optionally working with older google play game services versions.

You can send logs and apks to support@heyzap.com and we can determine what the problem is for you.

Comment: so this wont stop from serving ads ?. I thought this was the reason why I wasn't getting ads. I was trying to serve Vungle for the last 2 days. Not even 1 impression till now.